# Joomla database settings

Tags: php, database, configuration, joomla, settings

What is the file, where database setting are stored in Joomla CMS?

Like server, user name, database name and password?

Something like WordPress `wp-config.php` file.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`configuration.php` in the root directory.

The variables of interest are `$db`, `$dbprefix`, `$user` and `$password`.